# Solve $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\alpha,0)}(1+\tfrac{x}{y})^y$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Compute $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(\alpha,0)} \bigg(1+\frac{x}{y}\bigg)^y.$

I tried using polar coordinates but it becomes very complex.

Comment: Write $$(1+x/y)^{y} = \exp(y \ln(1+x/y)) = \exp(y \ln(y+x) - y \ln y)$$ As the exponential is continuous, you can take the limit 'into' the argument and evaluate $$\exp \left( \lim_{(x,y) \to (a,0)} y \ln(y+x) - y \ln y \right)$$

Comment: @Mattos second term can be evaluated using L'Hop, but how to evaluate first term

Comment: For $a \ne 0$ $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,0)} y \ln(y+x) \to 0 \cdot \ln(0+a)$$

Comment: ok thanks. …...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\alpha \neq 0$ the limit is $1$. I will assume that $\alpha >0$ and I will take limit as $y \to 0$ through positive values. If you take limit through negative values of $y$ you run into problems. [$t^{y}$ for negative values of $t$ involve multi-valued complex expressions]. Similar problem exists if $\alpha <0$.  Note that $y\log(1+\frac x y)= y(\log\, x -\log \, y)+y\log(1+\frac y x)$. Clearly, $y(\log\, x -\log \, y) \to 0$ as $y \to 0$ uniformly for $x$ bounded. We only have to look at the limit of $y\log(1+\frac y x)$. For $x$ close to $\alpha (\neq 0)$ this quantity also tends to $0$ by the fact that $\log(1+t) $ behaves like $t$ neat $0$. [You can use the series expansion]. It follows that the given expression tends to $e^{0}=1$.

Comment: PLEASE ELABORATE FIRST STEP. TOO COMPLICATED

Comment: Most willingly. Please don't hesitate to ask more questions. In the first step I am writing $1+\frac x y$ as $\frac x y (1+\frac y x)$ and taking logarithms. Then I use the fact $\log (ab)=\log \, a +\log \, b$. Also, $\log \, \frac x y=\log \, x -\log \, y$. It is well known that $y\log \, y \to 0$ as $ y \to 0$. (This is usually proved using L'Hopital's Rule). I hope the first step is now clear.

Comment: @J.Deff I have made some changes to the answer to explain why I am taking $x$ and $y$ to be positive.